# Optional variable in Graphql

Tags: sql, reactjs, select, graphql, hasura

I have a graphql query like this:

```
query SomeQuery($id: Int) {
  some_query(where: {id: {_eq: $id}}) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

when i run this it expects a `id` as variable. How can I make that variable optional? It should display all results when no `id` is given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way that I'm aware to declare a variable as optional but also have it ignore the rest of the expression in the way you're demonstrating here with Hasura.

Instead, you should define your query such that the variable you receive is the actual boolean expression and the conditionally pass in the variables from the caller. Try writing your query like this instead:

```
query getItems($where: items_bool_exp) {
  items(where: $where) {
    name
  }
}
```

This makes the filter optional so if you pass null to `$where` you'll get back everything. Otherwise, you can pass in the actual filter condition as the variable and get back the result you're expecting

```
{
  "where": {
    "id": {
      "_eq": 42
    }
  }
}
```

You'll just have to update the client that's actually issuing the query to use the right conditional logic regarding whether or not the predicate for the ID should be sent.

Comment: Hi Jesse, where does `items_bool_exp` come from? I thought it may be a nullable that can be ignored but on my api I just get unknown type.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged with `reactjs`, here is a solution for JS.

This is in fact possible but requires a bit of string interpolation when creating the query.

```
const generateSomeQuery = (id?: string) => gql`
  query SomeQuery(
    ${id ? '$id: uuid' : ''}
  ) {
    some_query(
      where: {
        ${id ? 'id: {_eq: $id}' : ''}
      }
    ) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: This gets messy if you have 5+ variables!

Answer (score 0):

This variable `$id: Int` already declared as optional for making it mandatory you need to include ! operator  `$id: Int!`. The logic needs to be present in the server to check if id passed is null/empty then return everything.

Comment: It throws this error: "message": "expected a 32-bit integer for type \"Int\", but found null"

Comment: This only checks for optional/mandatory at the client side, check how the schema is defined on the server.

Comment: This only checks for optional/mandatory at the client side, check how the schema is defined on the server.